# send text from website to email

Tags: php, html

hi i want to add fields in my website which make people send me messages direct to my email this is my code

```
<form action="" method="post" name="data_table">
          Contact Us
          <input type="text" name="name">
          <input type="text" name="phone">
          <input type="text" name="email">
        <textarea name="message""></textarea>
        <input type="submit" name="send">
</form>
<?php
$from = '<@gmail.com>'; //change this to your email address
$to = '<@yahoo.com>'; // change to address
$subject = 'Insert subject here'; // subject of mail
$body = "Hello world! this is the content of the email"; //content of mail
$headers = array(
    'From' => $from,
    'To' => $to,
    'Subject' => $subject
);
$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array(
        'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
        'port' => '465',
        'auth' => true,
        'username' => '@gmail.com', //your gmail account
        'password' => 'snip' // your password
    ));

// Send the mail
$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);
?>
```

and this error appear

> Fatal error: Class 'Mail' not found in
>   /var/www/html/ISPGroup-Website/index.php on line 322

the website was uploaded on server
how can fix it ? and how can i change the stmp details ?
and is there any another way that can make people sends messages from my website to my email directly
thanks

Answer (score 1):

sorry i re update my post ,

Try befor calling

```
use Mail;
```

or check include path in your php.ini

or check install by server root

pear install Mail

pear install pear/Net_SMTP

pear install pear/Auth_SASL

PEAR installation  guide: http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.checking.php

or try to use [phpmailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) As an alternative

Comment: ok i follow your post and install the pear now i have this error :-
`require_once(): Failed opening required 'directory/Mail.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/html/ISPGroup-Website/index.php on line 310`

Comment: here you try to include file name (mail.php) is it exist in the directory ? no for that you have an error message , my frind use PHPMailer or call your root server to resolve your problem with (mail class) ,

Answer (score 0):

Try including the `Mail.php`;

```
require('../php/Mail.php');
```

Comment: still the same error :-
Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'Mail.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/html/ISPGroup-Website/index.php on line 310

Comment: I think you need to install `PEAR` for that If  have not already done that. Check [this](https://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail.factory.php) & [Installation Guide](https://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.php)